# Unable to find cookies on my machine but can read their values

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, cookies

I was working on a asp.net website and used cookies there. I can retrieve the cookie value but  they are not showing in the AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies location.
Please let me know any other place where this cookie might be stored.
EDIT: I also tried looking at the "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files" location but could not find them here.

Comment: Sometimes they are inside hidden folders, try to change the property to view the hidden folders as well and check if you see any cookies files.

Comment: it was already on but i did not find any hidden cookie.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by finding the cookie in a file?

Comment: I am looking to find out how is my data stored in the cookie whether encrypted or not and can it be accessed by someone else. I can see the other sites i access creating cookies but not my site i am working on, so i am curious to know why its happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can try here : C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Packages\XXXXXX\AC\INetCookies

Comment: There is no packages folder inside the Local folder given in the above path.

Comment: C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies for Windows 8 & Windows 8.1

Comment: I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Very strange, the cookies must be in AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies on windows 7.